# How to create unit test cases with Vue, Karma, browserify

Tags: vue.js, karma-jasmine

I am trying to build some unit test cases to my existing Vue project.
I found some documents there but not useful especially for testing on functions such as Watch, Promise and Then.
Is there any specific and detailed guide line on unit testing with Vue and these plugins?

The target vue has defined a function named test.

```
const vm = new Vue(target).$mount();
vm.test("message");
```

But the error message is vm.test is not a function
I do not know why I could not use the function defined in the target.vue.
Meanwhile once I use the test function to change some data, the target vue will update the data automatically.
But it seems that Vue.nextTick does not work on this situation.
Could someone help me on this point?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Also as the vue has a promise function to load data and render the page, how could we test the page content once data loading process done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hellocomponent

```
export default {
  name: 'hello',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App',
      test: 'Testing'
    }
  }
}
```

Hello.spec.js //for testing Hello.vue

```
describe('Hello', () => {
  it('set correct default data', () => {
    expect(typeof Hello.data).to.equal('function')
    assert.typeOf(Hello.data, 'function')
    const defaultdata = Hello.data()
    expect(defaultdata.test).to.be.a('string')
    expect(defaultdata.test).to.equal('Testing')
  })
})
```

This is test case of Hello component of vue.js which is created automatically when new template is created. This is using Karma+Mocha+Chai.